# Crystal Reports: Creating object that can be selected in viewer and then records time and data stamp into a database or spreadsheet

Tags: object, crystal-reports

Creating a report and need to log outside of the report when the last time the each object was selected and the user info from who selected it in the report viewer.  Didn't know which command set to import to start trying to create this.

Comment: Please consider improving your question so that people are able to help you. The way its currently written it is not very understandable I think. You might start with reading this guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am looking to have an object (think of a check box) that when selected will record the current data and user in an database to be tracked separately from this report.  The current date and user will be within the base report already.  I do not know what kind of command to use to record the information in a place outside this report.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to log Crystal Reports use in a viewer, but you mention "objects" and "checkbox" and those are confusing.
Are you sure you are discussing Crystal Reports?
If you are, then please explain "objects" and "checkbox" and the full context in much more details.

Comment: It is in Crystal. I used crystal report to create the report that is being ran by the viewer.  The last piece to create a data table outside of this report to track when someone accessed each grouped section of the report.  Someone recommended trying to use VBA functions to perform this desired task but I could not find a way to accomplish this while still having the primary interface be the report viewer.  That's when I thought I would see if anyone had attempted something like this.

Comment: Please clarify "track when someone accessed each grouped section". Provide more detail/context.